# A Syrian that wants to apply for a Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, tourist-visas

So, I am a Syrian National that have no connection to Syria whatsoever,

I want to apply for a tourist/visit visa to any Schengen country "the easiest", and I actually don't intend to travel their. The reason behind getting the visa is that I want to have a Schengen visa on my passport so that if one day I actually want to go on a holiday with the wifey it wont be as difficult to get a visa as it might be now.

I am unemployed at the moment.

Oh and my passport is brand new as my older passport expired and I just got this one.

Any Ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: You can try Portugal or Spain.

Comment: I'm sorry but your premise doesn't make much sense. You don't need a visa now, since you have no intention of travelling. Further, your unemployment makes rejection a real possibility. A rejection would make it harder to get a visa in the future. In contrast, I assume that you won't want to take your wife on holiday until you have a job. Once you have a job, it will be _easier_ to get a visa, not harder.

Comment: There was a pretty heavy edit that cut out most of the original question. Even though not all of it may ne relevant, a lot of it was to understand the premise of the question.

Comment: @jcaron My comment was made before those edits and still stands. The premise makes no sense, even with the background explained, and the consequences of the asker's plan are likely to be worse than the obvious plan of just waiting until they want to travel and applying for a visa then.

Answer (score 4):

Having an unused Schengen visa in your travel history would be weird. If you do get it, then **use it**, enjoy the vacation, and leave again on time. That's how you build a positive travel history.

The visa officials will try to judge your ties to your current place of residence. They will look for your residency status there and for a stable income and expenditures.

So they should treat you much like any other resident of Turkey with several years left on the permit, no job, and some savings. The job will be **much** more important than the savings because you could easily take the savings with you, while a well-paid job is a good reason to return.

In practice, being a Syrian will make it a little bit harder for you because of the suspicion that you want to immigrate into the EU. You wouldn't actually have good chances on an asylum claim because of your residency in Turkey.

So the comment by Richard makes sense; first find a job and then apply for a visa.

Comment: @L.North, for fairness ask on Politics and not on Travel. Quite a lot of people apply for asylum in Europe who do not qualify under the rules. Then there is a lengthy and expensive legal procedure to validate the claims, and some people in Europe don't want to pay for the ideals they wrote into their laws.

Comment: @L.North Just wait a few months and then apply for the visa for your summer holiday, within 3 months or less of the date you wish to travel. There is no need to do it now; it's too early. I don't know why your agent would have given you such bad advice. It's usually better to learn the visa process and do it yourself anyway.